# Put the MySQL command output to a variable and also print on the screen?

Tags: mysql, linux, bash, shell

I'm really ashamed to ask this question but is there really a way to redirect a MySQL output (e.g. ls -l) to STDOUT and also assign to a variable at the same time? I tried this:

```
san@pcjq:~$ exec 5>&1
san@pcjq:~$ SQL=$(mysql -uroot -p mysql -e "SELECT Host,User,Password FROM user;" | tee >(cat - >&5))
Enter password: 
Host    User    Password
127.0.0.1   root    *CD0B39440D9701958FDA10ED6B02E3507DC28EB
%   slvUser *8E6F445A9F0E7AA18DA1D830CC61B5AAC9C606
localhost   root    *CD0B39440D9701958FDA10ED6B02E3507DC28EB
localhost   san *8E6F4A10ED6B00E7AA18DA10EDD830CC61B5AAC9C606
localhost   debian-sys-maint    *1BF46B679FC8911CD06712EC782E446F01201CB7
```

which is not really the exact representation of the output that we normally see on the screen. On the other hand:

```
SQL=$(mysql -uroot -p mysql -e "SELECT Host,User FROM user;" >&2)
```

does print the correct output on the screen but noting gets in the variable (for obvious reason). Does anyone know any a workaround? Cheers!!

Comment: ```txt=`mysql....`; echo $txt > file.txt```?

Comment: @Marc B: you are missing the point: the intention is not directing the output to a file but a variable and printing on the screen at the same time. Cheers!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answering to my own question:

```
san@pcjq:~$ SQL=$(mysql -uroot -p mysql -t -e "SELECT Host,User FROM user;" \
| tee /dev/tty) && { echo "This is the ECHO:"; echo "$SQL"; }
Enter password: 
+-----------+------------------+
| Host      | User             |
+-----------+------------------+
| %         | slvUser          |
| 127.0.0.1 | root             |
| localhost | debian-sys-maint |
| localhost | root             |
| localhost | santanu          |
+-----------+------------------+
This is the ECHO:
+-----------+------------------+
| Host      | User             |
+-----------+------------------+
| %         | slvUser          |
| 127.0.0.1 | root             |
| localhost | debian-sys-maint |
| localhost | root             |
| localhost | santanu          |
+-----------+------------------+
```

`-t` is the magic option. From MySQL man page:

> --table, -t
>
> ```
>        Display output in table format. This is the default for interactive use, 
>        but can be used to produce table output in batch mode.
> ```

Cheers!!

Comment: Why are you outputting twice though? The bit including && and after it is not neccessary?

Comment: @Elendurwen, I've forgotton what I was doing with that 6 yrs. ago (when asked) but reading the question again, the thing after `&&` is ony to display that the command before is printing output on the screen and also putting the valure in the variable _SQL_  at the same time. -S

Comment: Ah, gotcha @MacUsers

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like

```
# mysql -u [user] -p[password] mydb -e "select * from [table]" > out.txt
# cat out.txt
```

or

```
# echo $(mysql -u [user] -p[password] mydb -e "select * from [table]")
```

Maybe the password prompt is messing you up here.

*keep in mind you have to do this if 'secret' is your password:

```
# mysql -u [user] -psecret ....
```

Hope this helps,
Harlin

Comment: As I already said above, I'm not trying to redirect the output to a file. And passing password inline doesn't make it any different at all. Originally, the password (and the UserName is being passed in a script as `optgets` options with default value. Cheers!!